# Get input value and generate multiple textarea and set value there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I have a DOM like this, when i fill the input field and click the button i need to create a `textarea` element and and stored the input value there.
if i click multiple times create multiple `textarea` and multiple ID's, How can i do this please check my code, Best answers must be appreciated

```js
$('#note').on('click', function(){
 var storedNoteVal = $('#enterVal').val();
 var count_id = 1;
 var noteCov = $('.note_cover');
 $('#content_bag').prepend('<div class="full-width note_cover" id="noteId"><textarea></textarea></div>');
 $(noteCov).find('textarea').val(storedNoteVal);
 $(noteCov).each(function(index, element) {
     $(this).attr('id', 'noteId' + count_id);
     count_id++;
 });
   
});
```

```css
.full-width.note_cover {
    float: left;
 margin-bottom:15px;
}
.note_cover textarea {
    height: auto !important;
    height: 45px !important;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
 /*border:none;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 mtp" id="content_bag">
            
</div><!-- #content_bag -->

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter project Tags" class="majorInp" id="enterVal" />
<button id="note">click me</button>
```

Comment: What is `$('.note_cover')`

Comment: You don't have to write `$(noteCov).each()`. Just use `noteCov.each()`. Just a comment.

Comment: Oh sorry for that , this is not my full code.. if i get the idea i can make it. the note_cover is the outer div

Comment: It looks like you're defining `noteCov = $('.note_cover')` before it exists. Notice that your `.prepend()` happens after that, so the `.each()` loop only refers to existing Elements, not the ones added later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine, just put `storedNoteVal` in `text-area`, and `input` won't generate any `text-area` if its blank.

```js
$('#note').on('click', function() {
  var storedNoteVal = $('#enterVal').val();
  var count_id = 1;
  var noteCov = $('.note_cover');
  
  if(storedNoteVal){
    $('#content_bag').prepend('<div class="full-width note_cover" id="noteId"><textarea>' + storedNoteVal + '</textarea></div>');
  //$(noteCov).find('textarea').val(storedNoteVal);
  $(noteCov).each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'noteId' + count_id);
    count_id++;
  });
    
  }

});
```

```css
.full-width.note_cover {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.note_cover textarea {
  height: auto !important;
  height: 45px !important;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  /*border:none;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 mtp" id="content_bag">

</div>
<!-- #content_bag -->

<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter project Tags" class="majorInp" id="enterVal" />
  <button id="note">click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support brother.. i have stucked with this

Answer (score 1):

Building on Abhinshek answer -

Your code actually reassign id's to the textareas, since you loop through all the elements after **pre**pending them.

You could define count_id as a window variable (outside the click function) and then just use it.

Also, you don't need to wrap noteCov with $() since $('.note_cover') returns a jQuery objects array

```
var count_id = 1;
$('#note').on('click', function() {
   var storedNoteVal = $('#enterVal').val();
   $('#content_bag').prepend('<div class="full-width note_cover" id="noteId_'+count_id+'"><textarea>' + storedNoteVal + '</textarea></div>');
    count_id++;
});
```

This way each textarea gets it's own unique id that doesn't change

Comment: but it gives same ids

Comment: if `var count_id = 1;` is placed outside the scope of any other function - it's like using a global variable, then the `count_id++` always iterates the same int